# Export orderedtest to .exe

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, selenium

I'm writting test of user interface in VB.Net for my web application. I use Selenium to do it. I made one orderedtest and I want to export it in .exe.
But I don't find .exe when I compile my test unit project in VS. (I use Visual Studio 2012).

I want to export it because I want to launch this test suite when I deploy my application on one server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible. Microsoft Test projects always produce  (set of) assemblies.

You can execute the tests by deploying the TFS Test Agent on the system (or installing Visual Studio Premium), which installs the commandline tools that allow you to run these tests. Installation is enough, you don't need to configure it or even connect it to a TFS environment. The installation will deploy the tools required to run the tests.

You can run your ordered test using either the old or the new test runner:

- The new: `vstest.console.exe YourOrderedTest.orderedtest /logger:trx`
- The old: `mstest.exe /TestContainer:YourOrderedTest.orderedtest`

You would need to copy all items in the Bin folder of your Test project to your target system. You may need to include extra assemblies that have been installed on your development system and may not be available on your target server (references of the test project or projects referenced by the test project).

See

- [Running automated tests from the command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx)
- [MsTest command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)
- [VsTest.Console command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just need TFS Test Agent to execute it ? I don't need to reinstall all Visual Studio package to execute it ? So, What I need to export ? All my test file in bin/debug ?

Comment: I have install TFS Test Agent. I paste vstest.console.exe in one folder and I put all references of my project and all my bin items. I get FileNotFoundException : 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel' but I haven't this assembly on my comput and I don't know where can I find this. Thank you

Comment: You need to run the vstest.console.exe from its original install location. Use the search function in explorer to find the additional references, or set them to copy local in your test project.

Comment: Hi. Existing one tool which  include vstest.console.exe lighter than TFS Test Agent? Because this is little bit heavy for each customer

Comment: There is none except Visual Studio express.

Answer (score 0):

For running any ordered test using vstest.console following command can be used.

e.g. if you want to execute mytest.orderedtest then run following command

vstest.console mytest.orderedtest /Logger:trx

Run from the folder where the ordered test is present.