# How to run a list of tests with VsTest.Console

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, vstest

How can I run a list of tests using vstest.console.exe? The .vsmdi format offered a way to specify test lists, but that format is deprecated(?).

I can run an explicit list of tests on the command line, which essentially does exactly what I want, but if the number if tests is large (say a few hundred) then I will run out of command line space!

```
vstest.console MyTests.dll /Tests:Test1,Test2
```

Is there no way that I can trick vstest.console.exe into running a *list* of tests defined in any other way?

(edit: emphasis)

**Note: I don't want to change the test code, e.g add test category attributes or change naming schemes so name matching will select the subset. I need it to run a list of tests.**

The best I can think of is to run as many as I can fit within the max command line length, and repeat until the set is done, then merge. But if there is some way of loading a legacy vsmdi list or similar it would be a lot easier.

```
vstest.console MyTests.dll < testnames.txt

vstest.console MyTests.dll /Testlist:testnames.txt
```

Comment: You should be using the /TestCaseFilter switch instead.  It allows you to control what gets run.  Here is the [msdn link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand how that lets me run an explicit list of tests? The tests don't have e.g. a common prefix. If I make the filter match the names explicitly `(Test1 | Test2 | ..)` then I'm back where I started, will run out of command line space!

Comment: The filter supports more than just the classname.  In your case, you should probably be using the "TestCategory" filter - then flagging the test classes you want to run with the TestCategory attribute.    This permits you to categorize the tests in multiple ways and only run what you need with the filter at command line.

Comment: I can't change the tests (classnames, categories, namespaces etc.). I want to run a subset (e.g. 1000 of them) from a given list, that can be dynamically changed between runs.

Comment: Well, then the only option I can come up with is to break them into smaller subsets and run vstest.console multiple times on each chunk.   Sounds like you are in a tough spot with limited control over the test classes.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is run tests in parallel on many cores, with test assemblies being too large and unevenly sized to use as chunks. For example divide 50k tests from 20 assemblies into 50 chunks of 1000 tests and run N instances in parallel on N cores. This was easy in mstest but seems impossible with vstest. Reorganizing the tests into smaller assemblies for this purpose also seems wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can list your tests in a text file of a particular format and then feed that into vstest.console.exe like so.  Assume file is called mytests.orderedtest:

```
vstest.console mytests.orderedtest
```

The mytests.orderedtest has to be in a specific format.  There's an easy way to create such a test from Visual Studio and then you can look at the contents.

First, in Visual Studio, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, then select Add / Ordered Test.  This will create an orderedtest file with a nice UI that you can add your tests.  So, pick your tests from the list: Test1,Test2.  That will create a file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OrderedTest name="mytests" storage="c:\src\MyTests\MyTests.orderedtest" id="ed4d22c5-ab9a-4ebd-954f-65ac4c034338" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <TestLinks>
    <TestLink id="14c6766b-c22b-130a-ddb0-53d5ddd6eb1d" name="Test1" storage="..\bin\debug\MyTests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <TestLink id="24c6766b-c22b-130a-ddb0-53d5ddd6eb1d" name="Test2" storage="..\bin\debug\MyTests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </TestLinks>
</OrderedTest>
```

If you are going to create this manually, outside of Visual Studio,
note that the GUID in the id attribute is significant.  It is the only way tests with the same name are differentiated across different fully-qualified class names.  That is, the id is composed from namespace+class+method.  This article explains it https://web.archive.org/web/20160121132144/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2013/10/06/how-to-create-an-ordered-test-programmatically.aspx

Here's a routine that will convert the fully qualified method name into one of these GUIDs:

```
// convert the test (<Name space name>.<class name>.<test method name>) to a GUID
static Guid GuidFromString(string data) 
{
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider provider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hash = provider.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data));
    byte[] toGuid = new byte[16]; 
    Array.Copy(hash, toGuid, 16);
    return new Guid(toGuid); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? The command line documentation doesn't mention this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx), and when I try this it just loads the dll and runs it (all tests). This just looks like the ols mstest.exe command line style

Comment: I'm sure.   I tried it a few times.   I also found another reference on StackOverflow that shows the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29649319/75129

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Btw the other answer just omits the test assembly and puts the orderedtest-file as the input file `vstest.console somefile.orderedtest`, maybe that is what needs to be done.

Comment: This works, just need to be very careful to get the assembly refs right in the file for the specific version of VS. Terrible error messages from vstest.console, basically if you get one char wrong it just finds no tests :/  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Andres.   I updated it to reflect that the .dll doesn't need to be specified.   So do you accept this answer?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. I have another issue now, that running with an assembly `vstest.console file.dll` can run in the current dir, whereas `vstest.console file.orderedtest` always seems to run in a separate deployment dir. I will make this a separate question however.