# Creat azure build definition that runs unit test folder

Tags: azure, testing, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My ASP .NET Solution (net framework 4.7.2) consists of several projects. I am interested in having a build definition  (Azure) that will run my tests from a specific folder ( that folder contains some tests projects -nunit tests )
I have searched for information about this, but most solutions seemed constructed towards building & releasing, with all the tests in the whole solution being run.
How should I approach this? I will need to build my solution (Visual studio build ) as a task (?), but what should be the steps(tasks) to select and run my test folder ?

Comment: Which test framework do you use MSTest, xUnit, NUnit or sth else?

Comment: The test framework in us is NUnit

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do something like this [How to run a list of tests with VsTest.Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824191/how-to-run-a-list-of-tests-with-vstest-console) on windows agents if you prepare such file with list of tests from that folder.

You can find vstest.console.exe on this location on host agents

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
```

In that case you just need to prepare such file, put it in source control and run in your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> I will need to build my solution (Visual studio build ) as a task (?)

The answer is yes. That because the folder `**\bin\**` is ignored by source control by default. We need to build the solution in our build pipeline to generate dll files.

> but what should be the steps(tasks) to select and run my test folder ?

We could specify the specific folder in the Visual Studio Test task in the **Search folder**:

[image]

Or specify that folder in the option Test files:

[image]